# yield return IEnumerable in a background thread

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, yield

I Have the following method to return a list of files in a Directory:

```
    public IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetFilesRecursiveEnumerable(DirectoryInfo dir)
    {
        if (dir == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
        IList<FileSystemInfo> files = new List<FileSystemInfo>();
        try
        {
            files = dir.GetFileSystemInfos();
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { } //ignore
        catch (PathTooLongException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Path too long in directory: " + dir.FullName);
        }

        foreach (FileSystemInfo x in files)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dirInfo = x as DirectoryInfo;
            if (dirInfo != null)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo f in GetFilesRecursiveEnumerable(dirInfo))
                {
                    yield return f;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                FileInfo fInfo = x as FileInfo;
                if (fInfo != null) yield return fInfo;
            }
        }
    }
```

This method blocks the GUI. I Would like to run this in a background thread (single only) so that when a `FileSystemInfo` object becomes available it is given to the caller.

I have been able to make this method run in a Background worker and return an `ICollection` of `FileSystemInfo`s - but that returns the whole list, whereas I would like to yield items as they are found.

EDIT

Seems like I may need to reasses what I'm trying to acheive (maybe this calls for a callback rather than IEnumerable)

Essentially, I wish to index a Drive worth of files, but I would like to run this in a background thread. That way, I can process file by file (maybe Dir by Dir) and I can resume the process if needed at a later stage. So effectively, I wish the caller (GUI thread) to run this method, but be notified during the directory scan, not when its completely finished. So for example,

```
//My original thoughts, but maybe need to tackle this a different way
public void ScanDrive()
{
  foreach(FileInfo f in GetFilesRecursiveEnumerable())
  {
     //index file
     //record the directory I am up to so I can resume later
     /Keeping my application responsive to perform other tasks
  }
}
```

Comment: The fact is that this will run so fast you'd have to slow down the whole process for the user to see the updates come across.  Its pointless.  And the pattern doesn't match what you require--you'd want some kind of callback rather than a yield.  And considering you'd have to marshal each call to the callback onto the UI thread, *you would end up essentially running this method on the UI thread*.  Save yourself the aggravation.

Comment: The user isnt going to see the updates, but rather I am going to index the files. Rather than pass a whole Drive worth of files to the caller, I wish to do them incrementally, so I can potentially resume  the indexing of the drive.

Comment: Seems like you're facing a different issue.  Not sure what you mean by indexing, but you might want to [edit] and add a description of what you are actually trying to accomplish.  May get some better answers.

Comment: [This blog post](http://mnajder.blogspot.de/2011/09/programming-with-c-asynchronous.html) has a lot of information on this particular subject, maybe you can use some of it for your own needs.

Comment: You need to run the code that calls this in a background thread, not this code on its own.

Comment: I feel like the actual call isn't blocking your UI, it's the fact that it is happening so fast, so you are getting a lot of `yeilds` very quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yield` returns control to the *caller* untill the *caller* call the enumerator again, so the next value (if any) in the chain is `yielded` to the *caller* again.

So I would say, that `yield` itself doesn't fit your requirements.  In order to achieve what you think about you can use simple thread synchronization, where *caller* (main thread) calls on another thread a method that returns a *next file info*.

Or simply use some "callback mechanism":

Simple example:

```
void Main() {


   //start thread
    Thread t = new Thread(GetFilesRecursiveEnumerable)
    t.Start(..);
}


//called by thread as soon as FileInfo is ready
void FileReady(FileInfo fi) {
   ...
}
...
```

and inside the method:

```
public IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetFilesRecursiveEnumerable(DirectoryInfo dir)
{
    ...
    foreach (FileSystemInfo x in files)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = x as DirectoryInfo;
        if (dirInfo != null)
        {
            foreach (FileInfo f in GetFilesRecursiveEnumerable(dirInfo))
            {
                FileReady(f);
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

The code is not production ready naturally, it's provided just to give you an idea on subject.